# Capturar nome do computador e de Usuário

Tags: c++

Estou desenvolvendo uma aplicação e em um de seus métodos preciso capturar o nome do computador e do usuário logado na máquina, em seguida apresentar na tela para o usuário.
Qual a melhor maneira de se fazer isso?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Em ambiente **Windows** você pode usar `getenv("COMPUTERNAME")`, `getenv("USER")`.

Em **Linux** - `getenv("HOSTNAME")`, `getenv("USER")`.

Veja também a referência [`getenv`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdlib/getenv/).

Answer (score 1):

Complementando a resposta acima,

**`getenv()` retorna:**

- "Uma `C String` com o valor da variável de ambiente solicitada, ou
- "Um ponteiro nulo se tal variável de ambiente não existir."

O `linux` define a variável de ambiente que guarda o nome de usuário como $USER, logo, para utilizar a função no `linux` para obter o nome do usuário atual,
faça `getenv("USER")`.

O `windows` não tem uma variável de ambiente "USER" mas sim, "USERNAME", que retorna a mesma coisa (o nome de usuário), logo, para utilizar a função no `windows`, faça `getenv("USERNAME")`.

Você pode digitar "set" em uma janela de console/terminal/prompt e ver todas as variáveis ​​de ambiente atualmente configuradas no `windows`. Lá você deve encontrar "USERNAME" ao invés de "USER".

No `linux`, se você digitar "env" no terminal, verá que existe uma variável "USER", guardando o nome do usuário atual.

**`getenv()` está definida na `cstdlib/stdlib.h`**
Exemplo:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>

int main(){
   /*Para obter o nome de usuário no linux*/
   #ifdef __linux__
      std::cout << "O nome do usuário atual é: " << getenv("USER") << std::endl;
   #endif
   /*Para obter o nome de usuário no windows*/
   #ifdef _WIN32
      std::cout << "O nome do usuário atual é: " << getenv("USERNAME") << std::endl; 
   #endif
}
```